# Burp Suite does not intercept packages from my Firefox

Tags: burp-suite

I configured Burp Suite in my virtual Kali Linux on VMware and activated FoxyProxy in Firefox (again in Kali/VMware). However it does not intercept anything, rather websites are blocked with the below message What can I do about it?

> Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue
>
> [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) is most likely a safe site, but a secure connection
> could not be established. This issue is caused by PortSwigger CA,
> which is either software on your computer or your network.
>
> What can you do about it?
>
> [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport
> Security (HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it
> securely. You can’t add an exception to visit this site.
>
> - If your antivirus software includes a feature that scans encrypted connections (often called “web scanning” or “https scanning”), you can
>   disable that feature. If that doesn’t work, you can remove and
>   reinstall the antivirus software.
> - If you are on a corporate network, you can contact your IT department.
> - If you are not familiar with PortSwigger CA, then this could be an attack, and there is nothing you can do to access the site.

Comment: Have you installed the Burp Root CA certificate into Firefox? After enabling Burp clear all user data in Firefox to clear HSTS data.

Comment: This is consistent with not having installed the root cert.

Comment: @Infomania72 adding this in from the Burp docs, make sure this has all been followed :) https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/getting-started/proxy-setup/certificate/firefox

Comment: I thought this would only show if you had the cert installed, but I guess I'm wrong